# Join 2 tables where the first table has the time stamp and the second table has the applications opened during that time

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I need to join 2 tables in SQL Server. First data set has the total time spent by an agent on a particular activity during the day and the second data set is a breakup of that time spent per application during that period.

So, the first table has around 10k rows, and the second table has 60k rows.

Table 1:

| Employee | Activity | Date | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | Call | 12/20/2023 | 10:00 | 10:15 |
| Jeff | Break | 12/20/2023 | 10:16 | 10:30 |

Table 2:

| Employee Name | Application | Date | Start Time Stamp | End Time Stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | AWS | 12/20/2023 | 10:00 | 10:05 |
| Jeff | Outlook | 12/20/2023 | 10:06 | 10:10 |
| Jeff | Teams | 12/20/2023 | 10:11 | 10:15 |
| Jeff | Chrome | 12/20/2023 | 10:16 | 10:23 |
| Jeff | Teams | 12/20/2023 | 10:24 | 10:30 |

The resulting table should look like this:

| Employee | Activity | Date | Start Time | End Time | Application | Start Time Stamp | End Time Stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | Call | 12/20/2023 | 10:00 | 10:15 | AWS | 10:00 | 10:05 |
| Jeff | Call | 12/20/2023 | 10:00 | 10:15 | Outlook | 10:06 | 10:10 |
| Jeff | Call | 12/20/2023 | 10:00 | 10:15 | Teams | 10:11 | 10:15 |
| Jeff | Break | 12/20/2023 | 10:15 | 10:30 | Chrome | 10:16 | 10:23 |
| Jeff | Break | 12/20/2023 | 10:15 | 10:30 | Teams | 10:24 | 10:30 |

I tried the following code, however, each time it returns an empty table:

```
SELECT 
    A.Employee,
    A.Activity,
    A.Date,
    A.Start Time,
    A.End Time,
    B.Application,
    B.Start Time Stamp,
    B.End Time Stamp
FROM Employee_Data A 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Application_Data B ON A.[Employee] = B.[Employee Name]
    AND A.Date = B.Date
    AND B.[Start Time Stamp] >= A.[Start Time]
    AND B.[End Time Stamp] <= A.[End Time]
ORDER BY
    A.[Employee],
    A.Date,
    A.[Start Time],
    A.[End Time];


Sample data:

CREATE TABLE Employee_Data(
Employee varchar(25),
Activity varchar(25),
[Date] varchar(10),
[Start Time] varchar(10),
[End Time] varchar(10))
 
insert into Employee_Data values 
('Jeff','Call', '12/12/2020','10:00','10:15'),
('Jeff','Break','12/12/2020','10:15','10:30')


CREATE TABLE Application_Data(
[Employee Name] varchar(25),
[Application] varchar(25),
[Date] varchar(10),
[Start Time Stamp] varchar(10),
[End Time Stamp] varchar(10))
 
INSERT INTO Application_Data values 
('Jeff','AWS',  '12/12/2020','10:00','10:05'),
('Jeff','Outlook','12/12/2020','10:06','10:10'),
('Jeff','Teams','12/12/2020','10:11','10:15'),
('Jeff','Chrome','12/12/2020','10:16','10:23'),
('Jeff','Teams','12/12/2020','10:24','10:30')
```

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide **complete** desired output for shown data. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: It's a pity the code looks like sql-server rather than mysql and that the dates and times look like varchar. Also right join is almost never better than left join

Comment: @Akina - I have provided the sample data as requested.

Comment: Why do you think that you need in **outer** join for your task?

Comment: You shouldn't use varchars for dates or times, is 09.30 PM less than 07:30 AM (hint, the answer is yes)

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the rows whose timeranges overlaps (overlapping criteria - any range start is less than opposite range end).

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee_Data t1
JOIN Application_Data t2 ON t1.Employee = t2.[Employee Name]
                        AND t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
                        AND t1.[Start Time] < t2.[End Time Stamp]
                        AND t1.[End Time] > t2.[Start Time Stamp]
```

| Employee | Activity | Date | Start Time | End Time | Employee Name | Application | Date | Start Time Stamp | End Time Stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | Call | 12/12/2020 | 10:00 | 10:15 | Jeff | AWS | 12/12/2020 | 10:00 | 10:05 |
| Jeff | Call | 12/12/2020 | 10:00 | 10:15 | Jeff | Outlook | 12/12/2020 | 10:06 | 10:10 |
| Jeff | Call | 12/12/2020 | 10:00 | 10:15 | Jeff | Teams | 12/12/2020 | 10:11 | 10:15 |
| Jeff | Break | 12/12/2020 | 10:15 | 10:30 | Jeff | Chrome | 12/12/2020 | 10:16 | 10:23 |
| Jeff | Break | 12/12/2020 | 10:15 | 10:30 | Jeff | Teams | 12/12/2020 | 10:24 | 10:30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4thdWSCy)

PS. The query assumes that the time values in VARCHAR columns contains leading zeros. I.e. not `'9:15'` but `'09:15'`.